# Display sql query result with more than one answer

Tags: sql

I got a simple group by query

```
 var db = Database.Open("Tool") ;
var selectCommand = "SELECT COUNT(NoEmpl) FROM DTool AS NumberOfOrders Group by NoEmpl ";
```

I know it's working because if I create a webgrid. I got one column with the result in it.
The problem is that I don't know how to create the column with the group by name... I only have the result.

What I want:

```
John    3
Mike    2
Bob     6
etc.
```

What I have:

```
3
2
6
etc.
```

The fact is I don't fully understand how to show the result in a webpage. I just know how to make the statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the column you group on.

```
SELECT NoEmpl, COUNT(NoEmpl)
FROM DTool AS NumberOfOrders
Group by NoEmpl
```